# Fastest way to process through million line files with timestamps

Tags: java, performance, perl

So I've got these huge text files that are filled with a single comma delimited record per line. I need a way to process the files line by line, removing lines that meet certain criteria. Some of the removals are easy, such as one of the fields is less than a certain length. The hardest criteria is that these lines all have timestamps. Many records are identical except for their timestamps and I have to remove all records but one that are identical and within 15 seconds of one another.

So I'm wondering if some others can come up with the best approach for this. I did come up with a small program in Java that accomplishes the task, using JodaTime for the timestamp stuff which makes it really easy. However, the initial way I coded the program was running into OutofMemory Heap Space errors. I refactored the code a bit and it seemed ok for the most part but I do still believe it has some memory issues as once in awhile the program just seems to get hung up. That and it just seems to take way too long. I'm not sure if this is a memory leak issue, a poor coding issue, or something else entirely. And yes I tried increasing the Heap Size significantly but still was having issues.

I will say that the program needs to be in either Perl or Java. I might be able to make a python script work too but I'm not overly familiar with python. As I said, the timestamp stuff is easiest (to me) in Java because of the JodaTime library. I'm not sure how I'd accomplish the timestamp stuff in Perl. But I'm up for learning and using whatever would work best.

I will also add the files being read in vary tremendously in size but some big ones are around 100Mb with something like 1.3 million records.

My code essentially reads in all the records and puts them into a Hashmap with the keys being a specific subset of the data from a record that similar records would share. So a subset of the record not including the timestamps which would be different. This way you'd end up with some number of records with identical data but that occurred at different times. (So completely identical minus the timestamps).

The value of each key then, is a Set of all records that have the same subset of data. Then I simply iterate through the Hashmap, taking each set and iterating through it. I take the first record and compare its times to all the rest to see if they're within 15 seconds. If so the record is removed. Once that set is finished it's written out to a file until all the records have been gone through. Hopefully that makes sense.

This works but clearly the way I'm doing it is too memory intensive. Anyone have any ideas on a better way to do it? Or, a way I can do this in Perl would actually be good because trying to insert the Java program into the current implementation has caused a number of other headaches. Though perhaps that's just because of my memory issues and poor coding.

Finally, I'm not asking someone to write the program for me. Pseudo code is fine. Though if you have ideas for Perl I could use more specifics. The main thing I'm not sure how to do in Perl is the time comparison stuff. I've looked a little into Perl libraries but haven't seen anything like JodaTime (though I haven't looked much). Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please show a few lines from your log file.

Comment: Can you not assume lines are in order? Is there any reason you need to keep more than 15 seconds of records, or just the previous record?

Comment: Are the rows in order by timestamp? If so, then you only have to have the rows for a 15 second slice in memory at a time. If not, you might want to sort the lines -- then the task becomes a lot easier. Rather than loading them all into memory, you might think about an approach that sorts them by timestamp, and then uses a state machine to walk through the sorted files and emit the last line seen for a timestamp. You might also think about pouring them into mongodb, because then they'll be a lot easier to work with. But 100Mb files aren't so big.

Comment: lol Peter and jlordo edged me out :)

Comment: Format of the timestamps? Do all the lines contain the same record fields ? In the same order?

Comment: He's working within the parameters of the task he is assigned, and I'm assuming that he did not design this system which is why he is not using a database. However, OP, don't ever hesitate to ask the customer WHY they are doing this way and suggest a better process.

Comment: The timestamps are not in order and there is nothing I can do to the data. It comes the way it comes and I have to make due with it as it is. Also, I'm not able to make use of a database. IcedDante is correct in his statements, thanks for that. Finally, I suppose 100MB might not be that large, which is why I was confused over getting memory errors. Hence why I believe I coded this incorrectly and am looking for suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading all the rows in is not ideal, because you need to store the whole lot in memory.

Instead you could read line by line, writing out the records that you want to keep as you go. You could keep a cache of the rows you've hit previously, bounded to be within 15 seconds of the current program.  In very rough pseudo-code, for every line you'd read:

```
var line = ReadLine()
DiscardAnythingInCacheOlderThan(line.Date().Minus(15 seconds);
if (!cache.ContainsSomethingMatchingCriteria()) {
   // it's a line we want to keep
   WriteLine(line);
}

UpdateCache(line);  // make sure we store this line so we don't write it out again.
```

As pointed out, this assumes that the lines are in time stamp order.  If they aren't, then I'd just use UNIX `sort` to make it so they are, as that'll quite merrily handle extremely large files.

Comment: I didn't know about the sort function. I'll have to look into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might read the file and output just the line numbers to be deleted (to be sorted and used in a separate pass.)  Your hash map could then contain just the minimum data needed plus the line number.  This could save a lot of memory if the data needed is small compared to the line size.